# Local Transactions are invasive to programming model

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am reading a section from Spring Framework user guide http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html  . In section 12.2.2 , it mentioned "Another downside is that local transactions are invasive to the programming model." . I don't quite understand in what way are they invasive to programming.

How are local transactions invasive to the programming model?